# How to remove duplicates with special extension in folder

Tags: linux, centos

I am using CentOS and I have downloaded several videos which due to the bad internet has corrupted duplicated files with names. I want to remove them.

the files are with

```
file1.mp4
file1.mp4.0
file2.mp4
file2.mp4.0
file2.mp4.1
file3.mp4
file3.mp4.0
file3.mp4.1
file3.mp4.2
```

I want to remove all with the `.mp4.0` and `.mp4.1` and so on duplicated extensions.

I tried

```sh
rm *{.mp4.0}
rm *.mp4.0
```

but files are still there. What is the missing command part which can make the problem solved.
The file has thousands of duplicated such files and the folder contains hundreds of thousands of files.

Comment: Use `rm file*.mp4.*`

Comment: "and both didn't work" isn't a very good description of the problem. What unexpected behaviour did you see? Were there any error messages? What do you see if you replace `rm` with `ls`?

Comment: will it work with the different file names? because the extension names are not in sequence.

Comment: Dear Dave, command executed without error. Files are still there.

Comment: If the files are named as you say and you're using the commands you show, then I can see no reason why it would fail without an error message. What do you see if you replace `rm` with `ls`? Do the actual filenames contain any strange characters?

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are 2 'dynamic' parts, you'll need to use 2 wildcards

---

Using [`rm`](https://ss64.com/bash/rm.html):

```sh
rm *.mp4.*
```

---

Using [`find`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

```sh
find . -type f -iname '*.mp4.*' -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

> rm file*
> will remove all files that begin with "file" in a particular directory.